# Service cant find .sh file

Tags: ubuntu, services, systemctl

I want to create service to host my bot. but my service cant find .sh file. i tried to create a new test service and it is the same. i have tried moving .sh file to easier access location but it still doesn't work (originally from `\home\<NAME>.config\systemd\user` to `\home\<NAME>\`). Every file has given permission by `chmod` to execute yet it still doesn't work. here are my files

**Error** from `journalctl --user -u test -e`

```
test.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/<NAME>/test.sh: No such file or directory
```

**Service File** `\home\<NAME>\.config\systemd\user\test.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=test
After=network.target network-online.target lavalink.service
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/<NAME>/test.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**SH file** `\home\<NAME>\test.sh`

```
#!bin/bash

echo "hello World"
```

**command** `ll`

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 <NAME> <NAME>  245 Feb 27 20:26 test.service
-rwxrwxrwx 1 <NAME> <NAME>   31 Feb 27 20:22 test.sh
```

note: the working environment is a 6$ VPS from Digital ocean, Ubuntu 22.10 X64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/home/<NAME>/test.sh`, you have:

```
#!bin/bash
```

when it should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You missed out the leading slash.

Brainfart, we all get them...

Comment: OH MY GOD i want to kms

Comment: @PapopLekhapanyaporn Don't worry about it, every one of us has made this same kind of mistake. You learn to check for the simple things as you go along.